# Проблема с выводом длины песни на экран

Tags: javascript

Есть функция, которая переводит длину песни в минуты и секунды(изначально дли в секундах)

```
durationInTime = (sec) =>{
    var minutes = Math.floor(sec / 60);
    var seconds  = sec - minutes * 60;
    if(minutes < 10) {
      minutes = '0' + minutes;
    }
    if (seconds < 10) {
      seconds = '0' + seconds
    }
    return minutes + ':' + seconds.toFixed(0);
}
```

Функция вызывается при нажатии на кнопки переключения на следующую или предыдущую песню(или при нажатии на кнопку проигрыша). После первого нажатия на проигрыш все окей, выводится длина песни как надо, после переключения вперед или назад сначала выводится  `NaN:NaN` и если потом нажать на кнопку проигрывания выводится время. Но если ещё раз переключить песню то выбивает ошибку: `Uncaught TypeError: seconds.toFixed is not a function`. Предполагаю что это из за того что в функцию не передается время но как решить эту проблему не знаю. Вот вызов функции(`this.audio.duration` - длина песни в секундах):

```
document.getElementById('durationOfTrack').innerText = (this.durationInTime(this.audio.duration));
```

Подскажите, как решить эту проблему.

Comment: `console.log(sec); var minutes = ...`

Comment: @Igor после переключений вперед и назад всегда sec = NaN. Но с чем это может быть связано?